# Creating a scrolling view with a textBox

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

I'm trying to implement scrolling functionality in a textBox, so that I'm only displaying as many lines as will fit on the viewable part of the textbox and discarding any other lines.

I have tried getting actualHeight and dividing it by the fontsize but this gives a line count which is too high so I display too many lines and the text is written off the end of the textBox which then increases actualHeight and so it continues forever.

I also tried using a textBox instead and using LineCount and GetLastVisibleLineIndex() but they both return -1.

Is there any easier way, short of writing a custom control something like [this](http://nayyeri.net/on-demand-rendering-in-windows-presentation-foundation), which will allow me to get or calculate an accurate line count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `TextWrapping` to `Wrap` and `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Auto`. If you want horizontal scrollbars too just set `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` accordingly.

```
    <TextBox TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
        dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et 
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
        sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
        dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et 
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
        sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
        dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et 
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
        sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et 
        dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et 
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
        sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </TextBox>
```

UPDATE: To achieve the desired terminal like effet you could just append new text to the end of the TextBox and scroll down to the end after each append.

```
textBox.AppendText("Some text.\r\n");
textBox.ScrollToEnd();
```

Comment: I have this just now, but I don't want to use scrollbars, I want terminal-like functionality where only as many lines as will fit on the screen are displayed. Do you know of any easier way to do this other than implementing a custom control?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of how to achieve your desired terminal-like result.

Comment: This is very close to doing what I want, but I can't have scrollbars I'm afraid, those are my requirements :P. Thanks a lot for you suggestions, but it looks like I'll have to write a custom control to get this functionality.

Comment: You can suppress the scrollbars by setting VerticalScrollBarVisibility to hidden.

Comment: that works perfectly, thanks very much :) I feel really silly for not trying that :S 

For the record, I wrote a custom control and that worked fine as well, although your method is far less complex. Cheers again